# Download Not working through HTML anchor tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, download

We are using GoLang as backend and AngularJS as frontend. The backend sends a file path as response and in the UI, I need to consume the file path and download it. The filepath is local machine path.

In HTML

```
            <td *ngIf="hasPackageDownloadPermission">
                <div class="package-icons">
                    <a href="file://{{package?.downloadPath}}" target="_blank" download><span class="fa fa-download" title="Download"></span></a>
                </div>
            </td>
```

From Dev Tools

```
   <div class="package-icons">
                    <a download="" target="_blank" ng-reflect-href="file:///home/usern/bbbb1014_pokg1039.tar" href="file:///home/usern/bbbb1014_pokg1039.tar"><span class="fa fa-download" title="Download"></span></a>
    </div>
```

In Chrome: 
Getting Failed - Network Error

In FireFox:
Nothing happens on click.

If I simply copy paste the file path that is returned as response, in chrome file is downloading. In firefox a confirmation dialog appears to ask whether to 'save file'.

Comment: Links from websites to local files are blocked by most web browsers.

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a): *the download attribute only works for same-origin URLs.*

Comment: So @NinoFiliu you mean to say, this is not doable?

Comment: This is perfecty doable but you'll need to do some code refactoring. You basically have two options: serve the file from the same server you're serving your front-end, or fetch the file via JS and generate a Blob (blobs work for download).

Comment: @Quentin I don't think this is a duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084312/linking-to-local-content-in-a-web-application) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711584/how-to-specify-a-local-file-within-html-using-the-file-scheme), neither of them specify issue when using the download attribute :/

Comment: @NinoFiliu — "The link doesn't work when I link to a local file" covers the case "The link doesn't work when I link to a local file and use a download attribute". The download attribute isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: @NinoFiliu — "fetch the file via JS" — Impossible. Same Origin Policy forbids it.